# Unable to change permisions on windows partition disk

Tags: permissions, sudo, chmod

I need to change permissions of files in my /media/MAVEN/Projects
MAVEN is my windows disk partition.

The permissions on the Projects folder are:

```
:/media/MAVEN/Projects$ ls -la
\total 340
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12288 Oct  6 21:31 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32768 Oct  9 06:32 ..
```

all the projects are set to drwxrwxrwx

I need to change them to 755 so I tried:

```
~$ sudo chmod 755 -R /media/MAVEN/Projects
```

But I get errors: `...Read-only file system`
The result of `ls -la /media/MAVEN/Projects` remains the same.
Help me resolve this.

Comment: Problem solved. I found out that I was using a package that was mounting my disk as read only. Its called pysdm I disabled that feature. Cant answer my own questions until i get 10 reputation

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
sudo chown username /media/mountfolder
```

Comment: I did as root: # chown techytimo /media/MAVEN/Projects
chown: changing ownership of `/media/MAVEN/Projects': Read-only file system

Comment: use chmod 777 instead of 755 !!